# Complemented ideals in von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $I$ be an ultraweakly closed ideal in a von Neumann algebra $M$. For example, this can be the kernel of an ultraweakly continuous homomorphism. Is it true that there is another ideal $J\subset M$ such that $M=I\oplus J$?

It seems like yes: for $I$, there is a central projection $p\in M$ such that $I=Mp=pM$, then put $J=(1-p)M$ - this is an ideal and $M=I\oplus J$. Is this right?

Comment: This is a different version of the fact that for a representation of self-adjoint algebra, if there exists a closed subrepresentation, then there exists a complementary closed subrepresentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is right, and of course $J$ is also ultraweakly closed.

Comment: Thank you; isn't it strange that such a nice thing is not mentioned in textbooks (Kadison & Ringrose, for example)?

Comment: @YuliaKuznetsova: You're welcome. Yes, I would think that it would always be mentioned in a textbook after the result characterizing the ultraweakly closed 2-sided ideals as principal ideals generated by central projections, but it often isn't.  It is mentioned in Blackadar's book on operator algebras, however.